# Paginacion en un RecyclerView Volley - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

Estoy aprendiendo a usar el RecyclerView con Volley, al inicio todo cargaba bien hasta con 200 datos. Tengo un problema y es que al momento de mostrar mas datos (1000), los primeros datos se muestran normal pero mientras estoy bajando para ver el listado completo me sale error del app. Me dijeron que se tiene que usar paginacion, no entiendo muy bien como seria eso.

Codigo donde cargan los datos:

```
private void CargarWebService(){
        progreso=new ProgressDialog(this);
        progreso.setMessage("Cargando...");
        progreso.show();
        progreso.setCancelable(false);
        progreso.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Url.url + "MenuActivity", null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Usuario usuario = null;
                JSONArray json=response.optJSONArray("Usuario");

                try{
                    for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++){
                        usuario = new Usuario();
                        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                        jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(i);
                        usuario.setIdUsuario(jsonObject.optInt("IdUsuario"));
                        usuario.setApellidoPaterno(jsonObject.optString("ApellidoPaterno"));
                        usuario.setApellidoMaterno(jsonObject.optString("ApellidoMaterno"));
                        usuario.setNombre(jsonObject.optString("Nombre"));
                        listausuarios.add(usuario);
                    }

                    progreso.hide();
                    ConsultasAdapter adapter = new ConsultasAdapter(listausuarios);
                    recyclerViewCita.setAdapter(adapter);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "No se pudo establecer una conexion con el servidor", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progreso.hide();
                }
            }

        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MenuActivity.this, "Usted aun no tiene Datos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        progreso.hide();
                    }
                }
                );
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MenuActivity.this);
        requestQueue.add(request);

    }
```

Codigo agregado sobre paginacion: Nose como utilizarlo :s

```
recyclerViewCita.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            }

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
            }
        });
```

PD: Si desean que muestre mas metodos necesario me comentan,

Espero su apoyo.

Comment: Hola, lo que pasa es que no puedes cargar tanta data dentro de un RecyclerView de una, tienes que paginar la información para que al llegar al final de la listar cargar los siguientes 20 items (por ejemplo) y asi poco a poco.

Comment: @Carlosgub hola que tal disculpa que recien conteste. Me podrias mostrar como seria eso? Por favor.

Comment: Es importante agregues que mensaje de error se despliega en el LogCat, las causas de cierre pueden ser diversas

Comment: @Jorgeys el problema es ese, lo que dice el compañero de arriba. No puede cargar todos los datos completos mientras hago scroll y de ahi sale el error :s

Comment: Hola saludos solucionaste esa parte? si tienes documentación pasa los links para saber como lo implementaste